# Where can I find AWS RDS logs for snapshot upgrades?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to upgrade some PostgreSQL RDS snapshots to version 13.3 from version 9.6.22

When I try to do the upgrade from the RDS console, it fails with the following error message:

`Snapshot upgrade-postgres-13-enc-an-rds-2021-12-17 is in a state that cannot be upgraded: patchDb 140753: PreUpgrade checks failed: The instance could not be upgraded because one or more databases have settings or usages that are not compatible with the target engine version. Please check the precheck log file for more details`

I'm utterly confused because as far as I can tell, there are no logs for this anywhere! Snapshots don't have logs, only RDS instances do. Just in case, I checked the RDS instance the snapshot came from and there's no precheck log there.

Where can I find the logs so I can know what went wrong with my snapshot upgrade?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to do the upgrade on a running instance, rather than on a snapshot.

Comment: That is difficult for other reasons, such as increasing downtime with our current setup.

Comment: Oh, wait. I could restore the snapshot to a db and then try to upgrade that running instance. That won't incur downtime. Just more money. I guess 'tis the AWS way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem at first, but finally found the log, it is simply in the "Logs & events" > "Logs" section!

[RDS Logs & event section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag3bm.png)

My problem was coming from the pg_repack extension, I simply dropped it, upgraded the instance version and recreated it.